# How can I embed hidden file in Go?

Tags: go

I want to embed hidden file, with embed package in Go. Such as git info.

For example

```golang
package main

import _ "embed"

var (
    //go:embed .git/HEAD
    head string
)

func main() {
    print(head)
}
```

But it occure compile error.

```sh
$ go build  
main.go:6:13: pattern .git/HEAD: cannot embed file .git/HEAD: in invalid directory .git
```

I tried those way, but didn't work.

- Make symbolic link and embed that
- Escaping and wrap with double quotes

---

### added

What does means `files outside the package's module` exactly?

It sounds like not about [go-modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules).

Why below file is OK but not `.git/*`?

```sh
$ mkir .hidden && echo "hello world" > .hidden/hello.txt
```

```sh
$ tree -a
.
|-- .hidden
|   `-- hello.txt  <- is package's module ?
|-- go.mod
|-- go_embed_git_version
`-- main.go
```

What is difference between `.git/HEAD` and `.hidden/hello.txt`?

Comment: To add to the answer below, `go generate` is another mechanism to create dynamic assets - so it could be used to grab the `git` commit hash & produce the embed file you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior is [explicitly documented](https://pkg.go.dev/embed):

> Patterns must not match files outside the package's module, such as `.git/*` or symbolic links. Matches for empty directories are ignored. After that, each pattern in a `//go:embed` line must match at least one file or non-empty directory.

A better way of getting the commit id into your code is by including it on the `go build` command line, as described for example [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications). If your code looks like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var (
    head string = "development"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(head)
}
```

And you build your binary like this:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)"
```

Then running your code would print the HEAD commit id from when the
code was built.

---

It's common to automate this sort of thing in a `Makefile`, something
like:

```
COMMITID = $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
GOLDFLAGS = -X 'main.head=$(COMMITID)'

all: example

example: main.go
    go build -ldflags "$(GOLDFLAGS)"

clean:
    rm -f example
```

Then you just type `make` to build the binary with the correct command
line flags.

Comment: Thanks very much and could you explain one more question?
What does means `files outside the package's module` exactly?

I appended contents at end of original question.

Comment: A file in your `.git` directory is not "part of the source code". It's not part of the repository, and when your code code is cloned by someone else, or exported as a tar archive, etc, it won't be available. That is at least part of what "files outside the package's module" means.